# WiFiDirect::Close() method is missing in API for C++

Tags: windows-runtime, wifi-direct, c++-cx

I'm writing a C++/CX program that uses WiFiDirect. Target platform version is 10.0.10586.0. Everything works perfectly fine but one thing.

The problem is that there is no WiFiDirect::Close() method available, though it's mentioned in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifidirect.wifidirectdevice.close.aspx).

The actual error I get is following:
Error   C2039   'Close': is not a member of 'Windows::Devices::WiFiDirect::WiFiDirectDevice'

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Also it's really suspicious that all Windows examples in C++/CX simply delete WiFiDirectDevice without closing or disposing as in C#. But this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Close` is not projected for C++/CX; it is automatically called when the object's destructor is called (or when no more references are outstanding).

See [the docs for `IClosable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iclosable.aspx):

> **Note to callers**
>   [**Close**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iclosable.close.aspx) methods aren't callable through Visual C++ component extensions (C++/CX) on Windows Runtime class instances. Instead, C++/CX code for runtime classes that wants to explicitly clean up a reference should call the destructor or set the last reference to **null**.